# Hapi encoding HL7 v2.7 message into xml using Hapi XML Parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, hapi, hl7-v2

Hapi xml parser is giving following exception while encoding the HL7 v2.7 message using Hapi Xml Parser.

> ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception: Can't XML-encode a GenericMessage.  Message
>   must have a recognized structure.

Below is my code snippet that i am using to encode message

```
HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext(modelClassFactory)
PipeParser pipeParser = context.getPipeParser();
pipeParser.setValidationContext(new NoValidation());                    
pipeParser.getParserConfiguration().setAllowUnknownVersions(true);
Message msg = pipeParser.parse(document);   
Parser xmlParser = context.getXMLParser();      
return xmlParser.encode(msg);
```

Any suggestion/solutions?

Comment: I tagged it with hl7-v2... hope someone can help you on this...

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown if the message you try to encode has no specific type but is a `GenericMessage` instead. It seems as if HAPI cannot determine the right message type for your `document`. If you increase the log level of HAPI to `DEBUG`, it might give you a clue why the `PipeParser` cannot create an instance of a specific message type.